# Add tabs to form using jQuery (cakephp 2.1)

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp-2.1

I'm using cakephp 2.1 just fine; I want to use jquery to have my form divided by tabs.
Already used jquery outside cake and got the tabs demo working. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/
I've also made jquery available to cakephp from webroot folder and

ProjectsController.php

```
public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));
```

add.ctp  (at the very last line)

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); // Write cached scripts
```

Where and how should I invoke jquery in my view? I know I shoud use something similar to the demo:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        });
    </script>
```

But don't know where in my view to do it and the sintax.

Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot !

This if my full add.ctp

```
<div class="projects form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Project');?>

<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add Project'); ?></legend>
<?php
            $arr_pr_subject = Configure::read('AR_SUBJECT'); 
            $arr_pr_status = Configure::read('AR_STATUS'); 
            $arr_pr_payment = Configure::read('AR_PAYMENT'); 
            $arr_pr_country = Configure::read('AR_COUNTRY'); 
            echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label' => 'Name:'));
            echo $this->Form->input('pr_subject', array('label' => 'Subject:', 'options' => $arr_pr_subject));
            echo $this->Form->input('pr_country', array('label' => 'Country:', 'options' => $arr_pr_country));
            echo $this->Form->input('pr_number', array('label' => 'ASC Project Number:'));
            echo $this->Form->input('pr_status', array('label' => 'Status:', 'options' => $arr_pr_status));
            echo $this->Form->input('client_id', array('label' => 'Client:', 'options' => $clients));
            echo $this->Form->input('pr_client_number', array('label' => 'Client Project Number:'));
            echo $this->Form->input('exec_id', array('label' => 'Sales Executive:', 'options' => $execs));
            echo $this->Form->input('pr_start', array('label' => 'Est. Start Date:'));
            echo $this->Form->input('pr_end', array('label' => 'Est. End Date:'));
            echo $this->Form->input('pr_notes', array('label' => 'Notes:'));
            echo $this->Form->input('pr_payment', array('label' => 'Payment options:', 'options' => $arr_pr_payment));
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
</div>
<?php
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); // Write cached scripts
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `<head>`, include jquery and jqueryui:

```
<script src="/js/path/to/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/path/to/jqueryui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then *right* under that, include a separate js file to keep all your code in

`<script src="/js/myscripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

In that file (myscripts.js) put in your jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Then structure your form input to match jQuery Tabs syntax

```
<form action="...">
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab1">
    <!-- Tab 1 inputs in here -->
  </div>
  <div id="tab2">
    <!-- Tab 2 inputs here -->
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle ! However your example doesn't seem to deal with cakephp.  I've already did the jquery tabs outside cake, just like you suggest. My problem is I don't know how to do it in my cakehpp form.   Can you help put this on cake? I've follow instructions to prepare cakephp to use jquery, just don't know how to actually implement the tabs for my form.   Thanks a lot  Please help.  Carlos

Comment: Ah yes, please forgive me. I left PHP a while ago and gave the universal answer.

Comment: I think that the answer is quite self-explanatory, even without a CakePHP code example. Just split your form between the <div id="tabN"></div< sections (where N is a number). Then it will all work for you. oh, and don't forget to leave the "Submit" button out of the tab divs. :)

Comment: Thank you  Borislav; you are absolutely right. Early yesterday I didn't know how to merge this solution to my cakephp form. Then it clicked me to remove all content from my .ctp view and build the form from the solution here, same as http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/, and it worked great and very importantly I got a better grasp on how to integrate things. First thing today was to pick Kyle answer with a note on integration for for cake first-timer as myself. Best regards and thank you for a great help.